# socket_write(): unable to write to socket [10053]

Tags: php, laravel, sockets

I'm using whatsapp api with laravel 5.2

> https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API

And i got this error when i trying to send new message

```
socket_write(): unable to write to socket [10053]: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

Send Controller

```
$massage = "Thanks for subscribe";
Whatsapi::send($massage, function ($send) {
$user = User::Find(1);
$send->to($user->phone);
}
```

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: This error also comes up when we simply reload the client page without properly terminating the previous connection.

Answer (score 0):

While following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@cn007b/super-simple-php-websocket-example-ea2cd5893575)

I was getting the same error in `phperror.log` which I have configured in my `php.ini`. Initially I thought it was due to some `firewall` issue, but it wasn't.

The problem was, I was running the `client` first and then the `server`. `Client` was probably not able to make a connection with the server when it ran for the first time.

So I resolved it by running the `server` first and then the `client`, which can now make a successful `web socket` connection.

**EDIT** : This error also comes up when we simply reload the client page without properly terminating the previous connection.